# Can I remove the _bin_deployableAssemblies folder in a ASP.NET MVC 4 project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

After upgrading my ASP.NET MVC 3 project to MVC 4 can I get rid of the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` folder and its contents?

Looks like with MVC 4 the application deployment is managed by NuGet packages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully removed it without any sort of problems.